# Why does an int kept on adding non stop

Tags: java, int

I'm developing a game. I'm really new in java and researched google: why does an int when added, keeps on adding java

Most of the times, it always adds even:

```
STOP_DAMAGE+=1;
```

Even sometimes, it subtract till negative. I'm annoyed. Sometimes it doesn't add too much. I do not understand. Here is my code:

```
if(isPressed==true) {
    if(STOP_DAMAGE<=5) {
        if(WAIT_DAMAGE>=3000) {
            ENEMY_SHIP_HEALTH-=SHIP_DAMAGE_ENEMY;
        STOP_DAMAGE+=1;
        }
    }
}
for(;WAIT_DAMAGE>=3003;) {
    WAIT_DAMAGE-=WAIT_DAMAGE;//time is deducted
}
```

`//WAIT_DAMAGE is a time int`

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - and ideally, stop using ALL_CAPS variable names...

Comment: Strange, I could not ask any questions but my question showed up.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
 STOP_DAMAGE+=1;
```

always adds one unless you have an overflow, which would be surprising.

It is far more likely you need to use your debugger to get a better understanding of what your program is really doing.

BTW

```
for(;WAIT_DAMAGE>=3003;)
    {

        WAIT_DAMAGE-=WAIT_DAMAGE;//time is deducted
    }
```

is the same as

```
if (WAIT_DAMAGE>=3003)
    WAIT_DAMAGE = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

**int:** The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive). For integral values, this data type is generally the default choice unless there is a reason (like the above) to choose something else. This data type will most likely be large enough for the numbers your program will use, but if you need a wider range of values, use long instead.

```
 int n =  2147483647;
 System.out.print( n+ 1);
```

The above will give you a negative value..

So once its reaches its maximum value its start from -ve value due to the bits shifting.